# Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Edition books or online training?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing

Our testers are in the process of evaluating Visual Studio Team System 2008 Test Edition. As they are unfamiliar with the use of Visual Studio, I would like to give them as much help as I can.

I have had a look on Amazon for books on the Test edition of VS.Net, but there is only one VS.Net 2005 test edition book.

Does anyone know of any good books, or online training resources with a particular focus on the features of the Test Edition of Visual Studio Team System 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also point people to the Virtual Labs on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/virtuallabs

In particular:

[Microsoft Visual Studio Team System Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/aa740411.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

For someone evaluating features who isn't that familiar with Visual Studio, I'd recommend the videos from a few places:

- ["How Do I?" Videos for Team System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/bb507749.aspx?wt.slv=topsectionsee)
- [ASP.net's Learn section](http://www.asp.net/learn/vsts-videos/)
- [Video tutorials at TeamSystemRocks.com](http://teamsystemrocks.com/tutorials/default.aspx)

Plenty of videos between those sites on the various VSTS Test Edition features.  Note that many are about VS2005, but the fundamental concepts don't change when moving to 2008.

Once they get the basic features, here's a summary of [What's New in VS2008 Test Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/products/bb933755.aspx).

See also:

- [VSTS 2008 Test Edition Home](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts2008/test/default.aspx) (BTW, there's a link to a trial VPC w/TFS & VSTS Suite on the right-hand side)
- [Visual Studio 2008 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8BDAA836-0BBA-4393-94DB-6C3C4A0C98A1&displaylang=en) - Not a lot on VSTS in here, but there are a few demos and resources that touch on the Test features, and it's a good general resource to have, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at msdn:

Walkthroughs for Test Edition
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182417.aspx

Web Test Walkthroughs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337591.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a book now available

http://www.packtpub.com/software-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system-2008/book/sb/msax-abr1/1209?utm_source=sb_msax_abr1_1209&utm_medium=content&utm_campaign=santi

Hope it helps some body else.

Sahridhayan

Answer (score 0):

Please check below links -

Visual Studio Team System Test Edition FAQ
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338734(v=vs.90).aspx

Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide (Version 2.0) Published
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2010/04/13/visual-studio-performance-testing-quick-reference-guide-version-2-0-published.aspx

Books on software testing with Visual Studio ALM 2010
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anutthara/archive/2011/04/04/books-on-software-testing-with-visual-studio-alm-2010.aspx

Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx